# Migrations are cancelled and duplicate column error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

When I write `rails db:migrate`, I get this error:

> bundle exec rake db:migrate
>
> == 20161209073230 AddActivationToUsers: migrating =============================
>   -- add_column(:users, :activation_digest, :string) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activation_digest: ALTER
>   TABLE "users" ADD "activation_digest" varchar

Here's my user table:

`create_users.rb`

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change
     create_table :users do |t|
     t.string :name
       t.string :email

       t.timestamps null: false
     end 
  end 
end
```

This is my `add_activation_to_users.rb`:

```
class AddActivationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string
    add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :users, :activated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Comment: check your `users` table, it might be already having a column named `activation_digest` which you are again trying to add with migration version `20161209073230` .

Comment: so that means I don't have to add any migration at all. I'm sorry, I'm totally new to Ruby

Comment: You can check the existing attributes of your user model from `rails console` - use `User.column_names` , if you have already `activation_digest` , then you don't need to add it again.

Comment: Yes it does have activation_digest. So this whole time I tried to migrate something I had all along. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activation_digest: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activation_digest" varchar

As the exception suggests, you have already added `activation_digest` in your `users` table.

You can check the columns of your `users` table right from the `rails console` with `User.column_names`.

Answer (score 0):

You are already having activation_digest in your user table.
Please check your schema.rb. If you trying to add new column then you need to deleted already existing one.